# Recording Mobile Device for Usability Testing Sessions

Tags: mobile, usability-testing, multiple-devices

Hi everyone i have a question regarding recording mobile device usability testing sessions.

- do you suggest any external device i can attache to the camera to record the test?
- if you familiar with mobile usability testing recording , what is your methodology or process ? what kind of device are you using to run the test?
- can you share some useful articles or links on the internet?

Regards,

Comment: Is your goal to record the actions on the screen, or to record how the user holds the device and interacts with your application?

Comment: yes this is my question